# Don't understand this IndexError using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, symmetric

I am given a quadratic matrix and have to do as follows:

```
For each entry (i,j) in the matrix
    If i = j:
        set y[i,j] = x[i,j].
    Else:
        set y[i,j] = x[i,j] + x[j,i]
```

I have made the following script:

```
def symmetrize(x):

    ## The symmetrized matrix that is returned
    y = np.zeros(np.shape(x))

    ## For loop for each element (i,j) in the matrix
    for i in range (np.size(x)):
        for j in range (np.size(x)):
            if i == j:
                y[i,j] = x[i,j]
            else:
                y[i,j] = x[i,j] + x[j,i]
    return y
```

I get this error message whenever I want to run the code with the following matrix:

```
np.array([[1.2, 2.3, 3.4],[4.5, 5.6, 6.7], [7.8, 8.9, 10.0]])
```

Error message:

```
y[i,j] = x[i,j] + x[j,i]

IndexError: index 3 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3
```

Do someone know what the problem is?

Answer (score 2):

`np.size()`, without an axis, gives you the *total number of elements* in the matrix. So your `range()`s are going to go from 0 - 8, not from 0 - 2.

You don't need to use `np.size()` or `np.shape()` for that matter; these functions aren't even listed in the documentation any more. Just use the `.shape` attribute of a matrix:

```
y = np.zeros(x.shape)

for i in range(x.shape[0]):
    for j in range(x.shape[1]):
```

There are better ways of producing your output. You could use:

```
def symmetrize(x):
    return x + x.T - np.diag(x.diagonal())
```

instead. [`x.T`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.T.html#numpy.ndarray.T) is the *transposed* matrix, so rows and columns swapped. `x + x.T` is the sum of the original matrix and the transposition matrix, so the numbers on the diagonal are doubled. [`x.diagonal()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diagonal.html#numpy.diagonal) is an array of just those numbers on the diagonal, which can be subtracted once you created a matrix of those numbers on the diagonal, which is what [`np.diag()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.diag.html#numpy.diag) does for you.

Answer (score 0):

You are using [`np.size()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.size.html) wrong way, it doesn't tell you how many rows or columns your list has, but number of elements in the array, in your case - `9`. You could use shape of your list like so:

```
def symmetrize(x):

    ## The symmetrized matrix that is returned
    y = np.zeros(np.shape(x))

    ## For loop for each element (i,j) in the matrix
    for i in range(x.shape[0]):
        for j in range(x.shape[1]):
            if i == j:
                y[i,j] = x[i,j]
            else:
                y[i,j] = x[i,j] + x[j,i]
    return y
```